# Equivalent autossh command?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am using the following command to setup an SSH tunnel to a remote server. I am using Ubuntu 15.10, and the remote server is running Ubuntu 14.04.3.

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:7154:localhost:7154 username@server -p 9999
```

When executing the command, it asks me for the remote server password, and then it works just fine. However, I am wanting to use autossh so that I can keep the connection alive. I tried:

```
autossh -M 20000 -f -N -L localhost:7154:localhost:7154 username@server -p 9999
```

But I do not get a password prompt. The command just executes, and the tunnel isn't setup properly.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the OS of both local and remote machine. Also, please don't tag with an OS tag unless the question is only applicable to that OS.

Comment: Rather than using a third-party-tool for this, why not use `ssh`'s own built-in functionality for this from the `ControlMaster`, `ControlPersist`, `ControlPath` configuration settings?

Comment: I wasn't aware of those options, thank you!